# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Tags: php, sql

Привет всем, делаю задачу на список студентов, есть метод в классе который возвращает массив со всеми записями.

Вот метод:

```
static function getStudentList(){

    $db = Database::connect();

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, surname, class, points FROM student"
            . " ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $studentList = [];
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch()){
        $studentList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $studentList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $studentList[$i]['surname'] = $row['surname'];
        $studentList[$i]['class'] = $row['class'];
        $studentList[$i]['points'] = $row['points'];
        $i ++;
    }
    return $studentList;
}
```

Потом я вызываю его и передаю в представление где вывожу по очереди каждую строку.

```
function indexAction($view) {
    $studentList = Student::getStudentList();
    include_once ROOT . '/views/template.php';
}
```

Все работает, но когда я хочу использовать этот метод в другом месте или даже 
если я сделаю так. То есть попробую взять массив и записать его в еще одну переменную. Как ниже.

```
 function indexAction($view) {
    $studentList = Student::getStudentList();
    $studentListTest = Student::getStudentList();
    include_once ROOT . '/views/template.php';
}
```

Код подключения к бд:

```
static function connect(){
    $dbConfig = include_once ROOT . '/config/dbConfig.php';

    $dsn = "mysql:host={$dbConfig['host']};dbname={$dbConfig['dbname']}";
    $user = $dbConfig['user'];
    $pass = $dbConfig['pass'];

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

    $db->exec("set names utf8");

    return $db;
}
```

То я получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean.

Обьясните пожалуйста, в чем причина?

Comment: Похоже `$db->query` может возвращать `false`. (Если `Database` обертка для PDO, то это вполне штатная ситуация.)

Comment: А почему в первый раз все в порядке, а во второй получаем false? Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6hjS4ldJ_TyNE1fVmZUTUpEZ0U     файл error.log . Коннект к бд добавил в главный пост.

Comment: А почему вместо while не использовать цикл foreach так код будет приятнее выглядеть и проще выполняется.

Comment: чет с этим PDO как то все не прозрачно...
мне кажется это нагромождение...
логичнее чтобы вызов подключение всегда возвращал как скажем в том же erlag либо {соед_ок, ДАННЫЕ} либо {соед_ошибка, ОШИБКА} перехватывает try case и все всех делов. даже на уровне конечного продукта мы сразу прописывает че делать при такой то ошибке да и все... вызвать падения скрипта тогда крайне сложно...(скажем чтоб на глвной стр сайта виднелась фатал еррор это позор)
даже если бд упал => вызвать os:cmd(["etc/init.d/бд start"]) конечно сначала следует статус считать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В функции connect() следует исправить строку

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

на

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

В этом случае ошибки соединения с базой данных будут вызывать исключительную ситуацию и вы будете их сразу видеть. Пока же метод query() возвращает false и падение происходит уже на методе fetch().

Возможно не стоит включать такой режим в продакшене, но при разработке такой подход очень полезен и согласуется с правилом - "падать" нужно максимально быстро.

Comment: Получил исключение PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in                                                               Но я до сих пор не понимаю как исправить и почему в первый раз все нормально, а во второй вот такое выдает.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не подключается второй раз вот этот файл $dbConfig = include_once ROOT . '/config/dbConfig.php';

Comment: Вы были правы. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score -3):

В условия `while` нельзя использовать `$result->fetch()` потому что насколько я знаю нельзя использовать функцию в качество условия для `while`, `if` и тд.
Попробуйте записать `$result->fetch()` в отдельную переменную.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, можно использовать функции в качестве условия

Comment: хмм значит ошибся.